# Multiple XMLHttpRequest.send or eventlisteners memory leak?

Tags: javascript, object, events, memory, memory-leaks

I'm currently implementing an upload for files. Because I've to handle huge files here and there I've started to slice files and send them in 1mb chunks which works great as long as file are `<~500MB` after that it seems that memory isn't freed anyone randomly and I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

### Prepare chunks

```
var sliceCount = 0;
var sendCount = 0;
var fileID = generateUUID();
var maxChunks = 0;
var userNotified = false;

function parseFile(file)
{
    var fileSize = file.size;
    var chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;//64 * 1024; // bytes
    var offset = 0;
    var self = this; // we need a reference to the current object
    var chunkReaderBlock = null;
    var numberOfChunks = fileSize / chunkSize;
    maxChunks = Math.ceil(numberOfChunks);

    // gets called if chunk is read into memory
    var readEventHandler = function (evt)
    {
        if (evt.target.error == null) {
            offset += evt.target.result.byteLength;

            sendChunkAsBinary(evt.target.result);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Read error: " + evt.target.error);
            return;
        }

        if (offset >= fileSize) {
            console.log("Done reading file");
            return;
        }

        // of to the next chunk
        chunkReaderBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);
    }

    chunkReaderBlock = function (_offset, length, _file)
    {
        var r = new FileReader();
        var blob = _file.slice(_offset, length + _offset);

        sliceCount++;
        console.log("Slicecount: " + sliceCount);

        r.onload = readEventHandler;
        r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

        blob = null;
        r = null;
    }
    // now let's start the read with the first block
    chunkReaderBlock(offset, chunkSize, file);
}
```

### Send Chunks

```
function sendChunkAsBinary(chunk)
{
    var progressbar = $("#progressbar"), bar = progressbar.find('.uk-progress-bar');
    // create XHR instance
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // send the file through POST
    xhr.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);

    var progressHandler = function (e)
    {
        // get percentage of how much of the current file has been sent
        var position = e.loaded || e.position;
        var total = e.total || e.totalSize;
        var percentage = Math.round((sendCount / maxChunks) * 100);

        // set bar width to keep track of progress
        bar.css("width", percentage + "%").text(percentage + "%");
    }
    // let's track upload progress
    var eventSource = xhr.upload || xhr;
    eventSource.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler);

    // state change observer - we need to know when and if the file was successfully uploaded
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            if (xhr.status == 200)
            {
                eventSource.removeEventListener("progress", progressHandler);
                if (sendCount == maxChunks && !userNotified)
                {
                    userNotified = true;
                    notifyUserSuccess("Datei hochgeladen!");
                    setTimeout(function ()
                    {
                        progressbar.addClass("uk-invisible");
                        bar.css("width", "0%").text("0%");
                    }, 250);

                    updateDocList();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                notifyUser("Fehler beim hochladen der Datei!");
            }
        }
    };

    var blob;
    if (typeof window.Blob == "function") {
        blob = new Blob([chunk]);

    } else {
        var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
        bb.append(chunk);
        blob = bb.getBlob();
    }
    sendCount++;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("chunkNumber", sendCount);
    formData.append("maxChunks", maxChunks);
    formData.append("fileID", fileID);
    formData.append("chunkpart", blob);

    xhr.send(formData);
    progressbar.removeClass("uk-invisible");
    console.log("Sendcount: " + sendCount);
}
```

If I attach to the debugger within Visual Studio 2015 it take a bit but soon I get an `OutOfMemoryException` in the send function at exactly this line: `blob = new Blob([chunk]);`. It's all the time the same line where the exception occures.

As soon as the Exception happens I get `POST [...]/upload.php net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` however I still got the chunks in my php-file.

### Here's a Timeline-graph of my error

[image: Timeline of error]

What I dont understand, I'm not able to see increasing memory inside the Task-Manager (a few mb of course but not close to 16gb ram I got).

So can anyone tell me where this leak comes from? What am I missing?

Comment: `_offset += length;` is a more-or-less obvious mistake

Comment: Why is `xhr` a global variable? I'm pretty sure you didn't intend that.

Comment: @Bergi `_offset += length` is a copy & paste error, or better a fragment of older code but thanks for telling me. and xhr [wasn't global](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36310120/3) just trying to find my leak and keeping code here up to date (global or not doesn't make a difference in my leak I guess) however edited it back to local variable.

Comment: Same problem here. Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780926/uploading-blobs-as-multi-part-upload-causes-neterr-file-not-found-on-chrome-af ?

Comment: @gpalomar I've changed my code and send the chunks syncronous with WebWorkers now so a got a single object for the whole upload, still the same problem even if the graph dont show a leak anymore. However I'm able to reproduce a similar error on IE.