# XHR file upload failing with net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm building a "chunked" file upload using simple XHR requests in an angularjs environment. After a random amount of time or uploaded chunks all upload-requests fail in chrome. The xhr.onerror outputs an "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" error.
Following suggestions from other posts I disabled all chrome extensions but nothing changed.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data', blob); 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.upload.onload = function(res) {
//success
}
request.upload.onerror = function(error) {
//error
};
request.send(formData);
```

Other posts also suggested a connection to the uploaded file size (between 200-500mb) but  the used chunk-size is only 1 mb.

Anybody else experienced problems like that?

Comment: So do you get the error if you do not send up the blob data? If you send up a smaller chunk, does it error?

Comment: I get the error when sending the blob data. First the requests succeed, but after a random number of requests all following chunks / files fail. Changing the chunk size doesn't affect the error!

Comment: I got the same error too. Looks like it has to do with Blob size being a % of total available memory. On android, my blob exceeded 6% of disk See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780926/uploading-blobs-as-multi-part-upload-causes-neterr-file-not-found-on-chrome-af